# Kinesis consumer asynchronous checkpointing

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I have a KCL (2.x) based consumer that processes records in an asynchronous manner. Each batch of records that is retrieved is queued in a bounded in-memory queue and then processed using an executor service. The problem I have is I can't do the checkpointing in the `processRecords` method anymore because in case of instance failure, any unprocessed records in my queue would be lost. Is there any recommended usage patterns to handle this? I have identified 3 specific scenarios that should be handled:

1. Periodical checkpointing while the consumer is working as expected
2. Checkpointing when record processing for a particular shard has been completed, which triggers the `shardEnded` method. Documentation states that checkpointing must be performed or all child shards will not make progress.
3. Checkpointing when the scheduler has been requested to shutdown, which triggers the `shutdownRequested` method.

The only approach I can think of is coordinating these methods in a blocking manner with my record processing thread to ensure that checkpointing is only performed once pending records are processed but I am may be missing something so your feedback and or some relevant examples would be hugely appreciated.